# When get build not Render my child components in Layout But when npm state It works right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, components, react-children

Layout components :

[image: 1]

```
return (
        <>
            <ToastContainer />
            <div className='font-IranBold'>
                <div className="border-b border-white dark:border-gray-500">
                    <ul className="flex flex-wrap -mb-px text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                        <Tab TabsInfo={TabsInfo} SetTabState={SetTabState} TabState={TabState} />
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

[Childs components in Layout :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2ylt.png)

```
  return (
<>
  <Layout TabsInfo={TabsInfo} SetTabState={SetTabState} TabState={TabState}>
    {
      TabState === 1 ? <Contentfa AdminAboutFa={AdminAboutFa} /> : <Contenten AdminAboutEn={AdminAboutEn} />
    }
  </Layout>
</>
```

)

When I run the project with npm start There is no problem and it runs. When I build, it only displays the names of the components :

[When run with npm start (open to show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ9WU.png)

But :

[When get build (open to show)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jLm6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Will need more info to suggest a solution. Especially what do you mean by this

> When I run the project with npm start There is no problem and it runs. When I build, it only displays the names of the components :

since the code only executes on `npm run start`, `npm run build` is only for bundling the code, we still need to start the app to see anything on the frontend.